# Task Object Page Layout shows more fields than Fields and Relationships section

Tags: fields

I noticed that on the Task object, the page layout offers a lot more fields than there are in the Fields and Relationship section. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Can someone explain what is wrong with this question. It is a clear title and genuine question with a great answer from the community. This is definitely one way to destroy a community

Comment: The answer was downvoted (not by me) most likely for not adhering to [ask]

Comment: Appreciate the reply - don't really know what part. Is it really worth damaging the clarity of the question with pointless research I did trying to locate the extra fields with no result? Anyway whoever the pedantic hero was, well done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is that custom fields are defined (in the UX) on the Activity object whereas OOTB fields are defined on the Task object.

Yet a Task (or Event) is an Activity so for the Task page layout you get

- the union of Task fields + Activity fields

and for the Event layout, you get

- the union of Event fields + Activity fields

Comment: All the fields were in the activity object - thank you